# remove duplicated value from array and replace it with the latest value in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an array in JavaScript. The user enters string and the data placed in this array in the form of value and name.

```
if(!_.isUndefined(args[1]) && !_.isUndefined(args[2])) {
    if(args[1].length !== 0 && args[2].length !== 0) {
        var dataObj = {
            name : args[1],
            value : args[2]
        };
        formateArray.push({name: dataObj.name, value:dataObj.value});
```

How can I remove duplicated value from array and replace it with the latest value the user enters?

So when the user enters: `value_1 100, value_2 200, value_1 500`
I expect to see: `value_1 500, value_2 200` (replace the duplicates with new data)

Comment: Are you using a library like underscore or lodash?

Comment: You will have to loop over array elements (which are hashes) and check if the hash's key is same as the one user has supplied, if yes, replace it's value with the new value supplied.

Comment: @andHapp its easy to say but hard to code!

Comment: @KylePlusPlus I use underscore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate your array replace the value if the name already exists.

```
function push(array, newVal) {
  var found = false;
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length && !found; i++) {
    if (array[i].name === newVal.name) {
      array[i].value = newVal.value;
      found = true;
    }
  }
  if (!found) {
    array.push(newVal);
  }
}

function printNameValue(array) {
  var out = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    out += array[i].name + ' ' + array[i].value + ', ';
  }
  return out;
}

var myArray = [];

push(myArray, {
  name: 'value_1',
  value: 100
});
push(myArray, {
  name: 'value_2',
  value: 200
});
push(myArray, {
  name: 'value_1',
  value: 500
});

alert(printNameValue(myArray));
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you please provide a jsfiddle? When I implemented it it did not work

Comment: I modified my code to use a function, and I created a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/D1mdd0xzA9tc23x9TdWW?p=preview).  The code is in script.js.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the array object, i suggest you to use an object that will act like a hashtable. You can define on this way `var formateArray = {};`

When you want to add or edit the data, instead of using push, you can do it like this:

```
    formateArray[dataObj.name] = {name: dataObj.name, value:dataObj.value};
```

If the key does not exist `dataObj.name`, it will be added. It the key exist, the value would set with the new value.

If you want the size of you array, you get it this way `Object.keys(formateArray).length`

If you want to loop on your data, you can do it this way:

```
for (var k in formateArray) {
    // use hasOwnProperty to filter out keys from the Object.prototype
    if (formateArray.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
        alert('key is: ' + k + ', value is: ' + formateArray[k].value);
    }
}
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/UwLzE/) is a jsfiddle that illustrate this.

Comment: Objects do not maintain a `length` property, but you can always do `Object.keys(o).length`, and `formateArray` is an awful name for a plain object... no?

Comment: Thanks so much, the explanation looks fine but it did not work. So after I added data in formateArray I create an object filled with name and value right? but it stores, undefined: undefined and when I wanted to print it with a for loop it did not show any data. could you put it to jsfiddle? I really appreciate it!

Comment: @plalx you are right for the length, i updated my answer. I wrote it a little fast. As for the name, i just wanted to keep names from the question.
 help

Comment: @user3249337 I just added a jsfiddle to illustrate this, hope this help

Comment: thanks indeed! it works fine but is it possible to change formateArray to array? due to requirements of what I am doing i need it to be array! like var formateArray = []

Comment: Hi again, can i ask you other question? suppose I want to print the result when the user enters a special string like: "display" and if he enters this string I want to show the result. I want it to be in another function but the problem is that formateArray is undefined. Can you give me any hint? Tnx –

Comment: @user3249337 You can transform your object back into an array using something like `var arr = Object.keys(yourObj).sort().map(function (k) { return yourObj[k]; });`. By the way, have you looked at my answer? I provide you a solution that works with an array directly as well...

Comment: Hi thank you so much, but I could not use what you suggested for transforming array or maybe I am doing sth wrong. but is it possible for you please to update the jsfiddle with your array suggestion. thanks indeed!

Answer (score 0):

Since your values can be associated with meaningful keys, perhaps you should use an object map rather than an array to store your values. Avoiding duplicates now becomes trivial since you cannot have duplicate keys.

```
var valuesMap = {};

//setting value
valuesMap.value_1 = 100;

//setting another value
valuesMap.value_2 = 200;

//replacing it
valuesMap.value_1 = 500;
```

Otherwise it's still quite simple, but less efficient:

```
function add(arr, obj) {
    var key = obj.name, i, len;

    for (i = 0, len = arr.length; i < len; i++) {
        if (arr[i].name === key) {
            arr[i] = obj;
            return;
        }
    }

    arr.push(obj);
}

var values = [];

add(values, { name: 'test', value: 1 });
add(values, { name: 'test', value: 2 });

values.length; //1
```